# problems with easy_install pycrypto

Tags: python, pycrypto

I'm trying install pycrypto on osx with easy_install and I'm getting the following error:

```
easy_install pycrypto
Searching for pycrypto
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycrypto/
Reading http://pycrypto.sourceforge.net
Reading http://www.pycrypto.org/
Reading http://www.amk.ca/python/code/crypto
Best match: pycrypto 2.3
Downloading http://ftp.dlitz.net/pub/dlitz/crypto/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.3.tar.gz
Processing pycrypto-2.3.tar.gz
Running pycrypto-2.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/3D/3D07iptvHZuzuYaeQDMFIU+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-00HgRU/pycrypto-2.3/egg-dist-tmp-BWGYsg
warning: GMP library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
src/MD2.c:134: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/3D/3D07iptvHZuzuYaeQDMFIU+++TI/-Tmp-//ccoXuPRo.out (No such file or directory)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: I just installed xcode 4 before doing this, could that have affected it?

Comment: Are you running on a PPC machine??  Your errors are complaining it can't find the assemblers for them

Comment: Try PyPM for binary packages, http://code.activestate.com/pypm/pycrypto/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a result of installing Xcode 4. It tries to build for ppc, although Xcode 4 no longer has the relevant bits for that. See this question for ways round it: https://superuser.com/questions/259278/python-2-6-1-pycrypto-2-3-pypi-package-broken-pipe-during-build

Answer (score 10):

I have this in my `~/.bash_profile` to address this very issue:

```
# Set compile flags to not try to compile for PPC (no longer supported by xcode 4)
# (this is required for eg building pycrypto)
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
```

Comment: This definitely works, but in case it isn't obvious, you need to open up a new terminal window AFTER you save the file in order for the changes to take effect!  Any old terminal windows will not see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

xCode 5.1

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this got a little more difficult with OSX 10.9. Here's the additional stuff I did:

`brew install libffi`

If you see the warning about how it's installed "keg-only", that means homebrew did not link it, so you'll need to provide some more info with `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig`. At that point the install blows up because by default OSX now dies on warning flags, so suppress that behavior as well:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Then you should be able to install with `pip`.