# python-crypto for OS X?

Tags: python, django, macos

I am trying to install a django project on OS X.  The instructions are written for Ubuntu and there is a list of dependencies.  Some I have found on PIP, others I have not.

```
apt get install python-crypto
```

How can I find this same package(s) on PIP?  If not on PIP, will I have to find their source and compile them on OS X?

Complete list of dependencies:

> sudo apt-get install git-core python-pip python-beautifulsoup
>   python-crypto python-dateutil python-dns python-feedparser python-flup
>   python-httplib2 python-imaging python-lxml python-memcache
>   python-mysqldb python-numpy python-openid python-reportlab
>   python-simplejson python-stats python-tz python-yaml msttcorefonts
>   mysql-server python-mysqldb python-setuptools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Depending on your Xcode version you may need to disable the ppc version by changing your ARCHFLAGS.

Comment: re ARCHFLAGS, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061180/problems-with-easy-install-pycrypto/6062869#6062869

Comment: This now produces an error: "**error: legacy-install-failure
× Encountered error while trying to install package. pycrypto**

Answer (score 3):

To search the pypi index, use `pip search` and try some different keywords. For example:

```
pip search crypto
```

and you'll find `pycrypto` in the list.

Then install it:

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Or just search on http://pypi.python.org/pypi to find the desired package. Different platforms/package management systems may use different names and sometimes Google can help find the aliases.

Comment: I've noticed most have the same names.  But I'm not sure how to be sure they are the same package. Does someone cross-check them all?  What's stopping me from making a package with the same name that does something totally different?

Comment: Search causes an error: **RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API is currently disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future.**